# Create Git Repo From Sub-Directory In Parent Repo

Tags: git

If I have a Git repo on a directory say `/app1` is it possible to create a sub-repo on a directory `/app1/framework`, basically I want to keep the framework inside of the parent directory, but I want to be able to clone just the contents of `framework`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't intend to add files in the subrepo also in the parent repo - that would probably be bad idea (although possible).

Yes, you can create repos under another repo, usually it makes sense to use them as 
[submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html). Generally I find [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html) a complete yet friendly source.

In case that looks overwhelming, here's a short summary: [Git Submodules Cheatsheet](http://blog.jacius.info/git-submodule-cheat-sheet/). The  extra commands you'll use in practice:

```
git submodule add pathto/subrepo        # to add/link a subrepo(app1/framework to parent one /app1, the first time
git submodule update  [--init]          # if parent repo is shared(clone), where someone else added a submodule [--init: first time after the clone]
git commit                              # an extra commit on parent repo to record the changes in the subrepo
```

Comment: Wow that is super complicated. I tried just creating a new directory  `/framework` and then symbolic linking to `/apps1/framework` but that did'nt work, since that directory is already under source control.

Comment: If things _could_ be that simple, in probably _would_ be that simple :) Maybe what you find confusing is the snippets in the manpage I first linked - but those are more that just submodule specific commands, they are a full runnable demo starting from scratch.. Just added 2 more links that might clarify things.. But yes, it does take some effort the understand the full story, and that extra complexity is not without purpose.